# Activerecord model has incomplete changes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a situation where the "changes" of my object have a couple of fields where the field_was value is nil but there is definitely data in the database for it.

The model looks a little like this (I've removed some accessors):

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Models::VersionLogger

  belongs_to :target, polymorphic: true

  state_machine :status, initial: :pending do
    state :pending
    state :confirmed

    event :confirm do
      transition pending: :confirmed
      transition confirmed: :confirmed
    end

    event :pending do
      transition any => :pending
    end

    after_transition :pending => :confirmed do |attendance|
      # do something not relevant
    end
  end

  after_update do
    puts changes
    do_something_that_uses_changes_or_was
  end

  after_initialize do
    if new_record?
      if DateTime.now.month === 12
        self.period = DateTime.now.to_date..DateTime.now.end_of_year.next_year.to_date
      else
        self.period = DateTime.now.to_date..DateTime.now.end_of_year.to_date
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine. In particular, the "puts changes" in after_update outputs correct data if I call x.confirm, for instance.

The controller calling this looks a little as follows:

```
class Thing::RoomMembershipsController < AuthenticatedUserController
  expose(:room_membership, model: :attendance, ancestor: :attendances) do |object|
    object.becomes Attendance
  end

  def update
    room_membership.assign_attributes resource_params
    room_membership.save
  end

  private

  def resource_params
    sti_class = :attendance if params.has_key? :attendance
    sti_class = :room_membership if params.has_key? :room_membership
    params.require(sti_class).
      permit(:target_id, :target_type, :period, :type, :status, days: []).
      merge(required_params)
  end

  def attendances
    current_thing.attendance_details
  end

  def required_params
    if request.xhr?
      {type: 'RoomMembership', status_event: 'pending'}
    else
      {type: 'RoomMembership', status_event: 'confirm'}
    end
  end
end
```

And "resource_params" is returning `{"target_id"=>"16", "target_type"=>"Room", "period"=>"2015/11/10 - 2016/12/31", "type"=>"RoomMembership", "days"=>["1", "2", "3", "4", ""], "status_event"=>"confirm"}`
for instance as an example of a PATCH.

If I find() an Attendance out of the db and do a status change on it, everything works fine (eg x.find(nnn).confirm).

BUT When a PATCH comes in like the above, the "puts changes" in after_update outputs something like this:
`{"status"=>[nil, "confirmed"], "period"=>[nil, Tue, 10 Nov 2015..Sat, 31 Dec 2016], "days"=>[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]], "updated_at"=>[Thu, 31 Mar 2016 00:19:16 AEDT +11:00, Thu, 31 Mar 2016 00:28:02 AEDT +11:00]}`

Those nils are killing me. It means I can't tell if the period has really changed or not and that's important for me. And it's only those two fields. The other fields work fine (eg days works fine).

But here's the weirdest fix (found by accident while debugging). If I just access the "changes" in after_initialize, everything works:

```
after_initialize do
  if new_record?
    if DateTime.now.month === 12
      self.period = DateTime.now.to_date..DateTime.now.end_of_year.next_year.to_date
    else
      self.period = DateTime.now.to_date..DateTime.now.end_of_year.to_date
    end
  end
  changes
end
```

That's it! That fixes it. changes now has the correct status_was and period_was values in after_update. But WHY? I hate a solution that makes no sense to me because I can't explain how it works which means I have no idea when it will stop working. Is there something weird about how the controller instantiates the model or how assign_attributes works?

Comment: Another alternative solution I've found is to call room_membership.reload at the top of the update function. I'm presuming that an empty record is being created, the defaults are being assigned and that's when the changes start accumulating. Hence the two nils. And then the db contents overwrite the object but those two fields are already marked as dirty.

So, additional question: is there something fundamentally wrong here or is doing a reload in an update an ok thing?